# How can I increment column value in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 excel sheets one is mapping and other is soneri. I want to increment the values of Column D in soneri sheet which was get by lookup function. What is the mistake in my code?

soneri sheet

[image]

mappingsheet

[image]

Outcome

Column D

[image: my outcome]

Only first 2 rows are correct of my outcome else are wrong.

Expected Outcome

[image: Excpected outcome]

Below is my code

"WORKING CODE EDITED"

Sub ButtonClick()
Dim soneriWs As Worksheet, mappingWs As Worksheet
Dim sonerilastrow As Long, mappinglastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim datarange As Range, assetrange As Range, b As Range
Dim entry As Variant

```
Set soneriWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Soneri")
Set mappingWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mapping")



sonerilastrow = soneriWs.Range("I" & soneriWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mappinglastrow = mappingWs.Range("A" & mappingWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



Set datarange = mappingWs.Range("A2:B" & mappinglastrow)
Set assetrange = soneriWs.Range("I2:I" & sonerilastrow)



i = 0
For Each entry In assetrange
    Set b = entry.Offset(, -5)
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(entry, datarange, 2, False)
    If entry = entry.Offset(-1) Then
        i = i + 1
        b = Left(b, Len(b) - 1) & (Right(b, 1) + i)
    Else
        i = 0
    End If
Next entry
```

End Sub

Comment: I cant see the images at work, can you explain what is happening.  Try removing `On Error Resume Next` see the errors.  Also if you are using this, then it would be beneficial to reset b and c as they may return the previous steps value.

Comment: Click on my outcome and  expected outcome to see images and I will check and update you . Thanks in advance

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I have removed the code and nothing happens . same issue has occurred

Comment: I assume you need to change your `+1` to something variable? Like `+x-2`

Comment: @RafayKhan.  I meant that security at work prevents the opening of images, so if you could structure in text if possible

Comment: @Nathan_Sav TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0004
VEHICLE-0011
VEHICLE-0011
MOBILE--0851
MOBILE--0851
 here is my outcome
expected outcome
TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0005
VEHICLE-0010
VEHICLE-0011
MOBILE--0850
MOBILE--0851

Comment: Please don't post that kind of text in comments. [edit] your question and format it properly.

Comment: If you feel like your question was answered, feel free to mark it as such.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your loop is only made for a single match of the Asset class.

There are a few problems here, but the if x > 2 approach would really only work if there was only one counter. Then we could substitute `+ 1` with something like `+ x - 2` (since we start at 3 for this part of the code).
But what you need is a counter that resets each time there is a new Asset class.

```
n = 1
For x = 2 To sonerilastrow
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
    soneriWs.Range("I" & x).Value, datarange, 2, False)
    soneriWs.Range("D" & x).Value = b

    If x > 2 Then
        If Not Left(b, 7) = Left(soneriWs.Range("D" & x -1).Value, 7) then
            n = 1
        else
            c = Left(b, 7) & Format(Val(Right(b, 4)) + n, "-0000")
            soneriWs.Range("D" & x).Value = c
            n = n + 1 
        End if
    End If

Next x
```

Another way of writing it would be

```
Dim soneriWs As Worksheet, mappingWs As Worksheet
Dim sonerilastrow As Long, mappinglastrow As Long, i As Long
Dim datarange As Range, assetrange As Range, b As Range
Dim entry As Variant

Set soneriWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Soneri")
Set mappingWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mapping")

sonerilastrow = soneriWs.Range("I" & soneriWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mappinglastrow = mappingWs.Range("A" & mappingWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set datarange = mappingWs.Range("A2:B" & mappinglastrow)
Set assetrange = soneriWs.Range("I2:I" & sonerilastrow)

i = 0
For Each entry In assetrange
    Set b = entry.Offset(, -5)
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(entry, datarange, 2, False)
    If entry = entry.Offset(-1) Then
        i = i + 1
        b = Left(b, Len(b) - 1) & (Right(b, 1) + i)
    Else
        i = 0
    End If
Next entry
```

But it's using much the same approach.

These however expect the data to be sorted on the **"I"** column, since the counter will reset if there is another asset in between.
If you want it to work even when not sorted, you could use something like countIf, like so: (Replacing the loop)

```
Set assetrange = soneriWs.Range("I2:I" & sonerilastrow)
assetrange.Offset(, -5).Clear
For Each entry In assetrange
    Set b = entry.Offset(, -5)
    b = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(entry, datarange, 2, False)
    i = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(assetrange.Offset(, -5), Left(b, 5) & "*")
    b = Left(b, Len(b) - 1) & (Right(b, 1) + i - 1)
Next entry
```

Comment: My 2nd row remains the same :( ,else were correct ... Whats the issue where i am making mstake in my code ... i have just exchange your code in my If condition?? and thanks my 80% problem has been solved :)

TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0005
VEHICLE-0010
VEHICLE-0011
MOBILE-0850
MOBILE--0851
MOBILE--0852

Comment: Yeah, it's a strange way do go about it in the  first place. I'd recomment remaking it completely, probably, but check if the edit works.

Comment: no it won't work... Here is output
TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0004
VEHICLE-0010
VEHICLE-0011
MOBILE-0850
MOBILE--0851
MOBILE--0851

Comment: Sorry, that's me not thinking straight. Move it up out of the loop. This might not be a great way to fix an edge case though.

Comment: your latest code shows this output
TEMENOS-0003
TEMENOS-0004
TEMENOS-0005
TEMENOS-0006
VEHICLE-0010
VEHICLE-0010
MOBILE-0850
MOBILE--0850
MOBILE--0851

Comment: Thanks a lot friend your 3rd logical code just had a minor mistake ; although it helps me a lot , I have got my expected outcome .Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 1):

Rows.Count returns that number of rows for the active sheet. Try changing these two lines:

```
sonerilastrow = soneriWs.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mappinglastrow = mappingWs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

To this:

```
sonerilastrow = soneriWs.Range("I" & soneriWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
mappinglastrow = mappingWs.Range("A" & mappingWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Also remember to clear any errors that might occur, otherwise you can run into trouble. Insert this before the Sub returns:

```
If Err <> 0 Then Err.Clear
```

I see you removed your "on error" statement.

I would also recommend that you force variable decalarations, as I can see you use undeclared variables, which will also get you into trouble sooner or later. Insert this as the first line in all modules:

```
Option Explicit
```

EDIT:

Please post test data "as text" next time to help people help you.
Here is a solution.
I uncommented your if statement, as it seem to not update the first record.

```
Sub ButtonClick()
    Dim soneriWs As Worksheet, mappingWs As Worksheet
    Dim sonerilastrow As Long, mappinglastrow As Long, x As Long, b As String, c As String
    Dim Dct As Object
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim CntTxt As String
    Dim PreTxt As String
    Dim Idx As Long
    Dim datarange As Range

    Set soneriWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Soneri")
    Set mappingWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mapping")

    sonerilastrow = soneriWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    mappinglastrow = mappingWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Set Dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set datarange = mappingWs.Range("A2:B" & mappinglastrow)
    For x = 2 To sonerilastrow
        b = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(soneriWs.Range("I" & x).Value, datarange, 2, False)
            
        Idx = InStr(b, "-")
        PreTxt = Left(b, Idx)
        CntTxt = Mid(b, Idx + 1)
        If Dct.Exists(b) Then
            Cnt = Dct(b) + 1
        Else
            Cnt = Val(CntTxt)
        End If
        Dct(b) = Cnt
    
        'If x > 2 Then
            c = PreTxt & Format(Cnt, "0000")
            ' Use this instead, if you want to preserve the number of characters
            'c = PreTxt & Format(Cnt, String(Len(CntTxt), "0"))
            soneriWs.Range("D" & x).Value = c
        'End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

If you are new to VBA I recommend that you learn how to use the Scripting.Dictionary.

Comment: I have already tried but outcome remains the same :(

Comment: You could provide your input data or example data and explain what you want to do in deatail.

Comment: Can you see both sheets which I have attached?
From mapping Worksheet I picked the value of "TREMENOS" and match to column I and paste it into column D in soneri Worksheet . Now i want to increment that value means if I have two distinct rows in column I (Sonerisheet) having "TREMENOS" so in Column D that tow distinct rows contains these values like TREMENOS-0001 & TREMENOS-0002